# Jquery forms with adaptive table from selector

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I need your help. Trying to build form in `php + jquery`, and have trouble with some functionality.
For example, I have this code:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="multiform">
<!-- Product selector -->
<table class="multi" id="MultiRow">
<tr><td>
    <select name="store[product][]" required>
    <option value="" selected="selected">-Product-</option>
    <option value="430">OCTA</option>
    <option value="440">KASKO</option>
    <option value="19041">TRAVEL</option>
    <option value="19063">HOUSEHOLD</option>
    </select>
</td>
    <!-- /Product selector -->
</table>
    <input type="submit" value="ok">
```

**How can I do that, If selected value is 430 or 440, then at right side insert**s

```
<td><input type="text" id="motor[]" name="multiarray[vehicle_type][]"></td>
<td><input type="text" id="deadline[]" name="multiarray[end_date][]"></td>
            <td><a class="del" href="#">DELETE BUTTON</a></td>
```

**If selected value is 19041 or 19063, then inserts**

```
<td><input type="text" id="location[]" name="multiarray[travel_location][]"></td>
            <td><a class="del" href="#">DELETE BUTTON</a></td>
```

**I need that there also will be +Add `button` and -delete `button` where i write:**

```
<a class="del" href="#">DELETE BUTTON</a>
```

**But for datepicker functionality I need that id for inputs will be unique, for ex: id="location1" , at next added row id="location2".**

Answer (score 0):

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gujabogve/6u98pq36/)

```
    $("#productselect").change(function(){
 var select = document.getElementById("productselect");
var selecedproduct = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;   
$("tr[id^='forselect']").remove();
if(selecedproduct==430 || selecedproduct==440 )
{
var html ='<tr id="forselect"><td><input type="text" id="motor[]" name="multiarray[vehicle_type][]"></td>';
html +='<td><input type="text" id="deadline[]" name="multiarray[end_date][]"></td>';
html +='<td><a class="del" OnClick="removetags();return false;" href="#">DELETE BUTTON</a></td></tr>';   
html +='<tr id="forselect"><td><a  href="#" OnClick="adddatepicker();return false;">add datepicker </a> </td></tr>';      
$("#MultiRow").append(html);

}
else if(selecedproduct==19041 || selecedproduct==19063 )
{
var html ='<tr id="forselect"><td><input type="text" id="location[]" name="multiarray[travel_location][]"></td>';
html +=' <td><a class="del" OnClick="removetags();return false;" href="#">DELETE BUTTON</a></td></tr>';
html +='<tr id="forselect"><td><a  href="#" OnClick="adddatepicker();return false;">add datepicker </a> </td></tr>';   


$("#MultiRow").append(html);
}


});

deldatepicker = function deldatepicker(id)
{
$("#remove"+id).remove();
}
adddatepicker = function adddatepicker()
{
var N = $("input[id^='location']").length;N++;    
var html ='<tr id="remove'+N+'"><td><input type="text"id="location'+N+'" placeholder="date"></td><td><button OnClick="deldatepicker('+N+')">delete datepicker </button> </td></tr>';
$("#MultiRow").append(html); 
$("#location"+N).datepicker();
}

removetags = function removetags()
{
$("tr[id^='forselect']").remove();  
}
```

It may help you for you work.

Comment: Thank you! It's almost what I actually need, but I need that there will be not [Add datepicker] button, but [Add another product] button.
I need to add one or more products, where products have predefined fileds for input. And datepicker will be allready in products fields.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is.
Since you need the ids to be unique I have used Date.now() and then object.now.getUTCMilliseconds(). That will ensure that event when you delete and reinsert another row with same rowIndex it will not crash. Then the rest is trivial!

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('select').on('change', function(e){
  
    var tr = jQuery(this).closest('tr').get(0);
    var cell = tr.insertCell(1);
    var now = Date.now();
    
    switch(jQuery('option:selected', this).val()){
        case '430':
        case '440':
        cell.innerHTML = "<td><input type='text' id='motor[]' name='multiarray[vehicle_type][]'></td><td><input type='text' id='deadline[]' name='multiarray[end_date][]'></td><td><a class='del' href='#'>DELETE BUTTON</a></td><td><a class='del' href='#'>DELETE BUTTON</a></td>";
        break;
        cell.innerHTMl = "<td><input type='text' id='location"+now.getUTCMilliseconds()+"[]' name='multiarray[travel_location][]'></td><td><a class='del' href='#'>DELETE BUTTON</a></td><td><a class='del' href='#'>DELETE BUTTON</a></td>";
        case '19041':
        case '19063':
        
        break;
    }
   
    
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" id="multiform">
<!-- Product selector -->
<table class="multi" id="MultiRow">
<tr><td>
    <select name="store[product][]" required>
    <option value="" selected="selected">-Product-</option>
    <option value="430">OCTA</option>
    <option value="440">KASKO</option>
    <option value="19041">TRAVEL</option>
    <option value="19063">HOUSEHOLD</option>
    </select>
</td>
    <!-- /Product selector -->
</table>
    <input type="submit" value="ok">
```